# Open app if installed else send to download - Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

So, basically, I am trying to open app if installed, and if not then send user to download it to play/app store, following the JS I have, it works fine in some device, but in some device its not working:

Actually in some device, what is the best way to handle this? Please note that I have link for both condition, if app is installed (if I hit this link it will open installed app) and as well as download link

```
<script>                        
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    }
};
if (isMobile.iOS()) {
    $(".open-app").click(function() {
        //If app is installed, 
        location.href = "//-open-app";
        setInterval(function() {
            window.location.replace("//download-link");
        }, 2000);
    });
} else if (isMobile.Android()) {
    $(".open-app").click(function() {
        location.href = "//open-app";
        setInterval(function() {
            window.location.replace("//download-link");
        }, 2000);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: see about fire base dynamic links ,I think it handles all these things

Comment: thanks for the question suggestion on this, but since its not our app, looking for javascript solution

Answer (score 0):

Add Intent Filter to your activity in manifest on your app. Below example :

```
<intent-filter> 
<data
android:host="www.yoursite.com"
android:pathPrefix="/yourCategory"
android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I do not have option to update anything within app, is there a way to detect using JS?